# View controller in storyboard always gets presented from bottom

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a view controller in a storyboard as in , [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ruJL.png)

I'd included the following code to show the particular `view controller`, but the problem is, no matter what code I use to make the transition, as if it's being pushed from side of screen(like `xib's push`), it always shows up from bottom.

```
 UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;    
  DashboardViewController * dbvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigForHomePage"];  
[self.navigationController showViewController: dbvc sender:self];
```

I tried with pushViewController(also Xcode says push is deprecated), but then the navigation bar disappears.

My storyboard has a navigationcontroller initially, from which I'd linked the other view controller's by ctrl+drag and the storyboard segue kind is show(e.g.push), but in-between - just for the dashboardviewcontroller, I included another navigationcontroller with a different navigation bar, is that a mistake?

I couldn't understand this concept, my question is how to get normal `push` like transition? any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
DashboardViewController * dbvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigForHomePage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dbvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: of course I tried this, but the navigation bar disappears from the screen, should I address the navigation controller in someway?

Comment: No, I have not I've added some more details to the question, please check it out.

Comment: In that image, that I've added in my question, you can see a disconnected view controller, that VC has a loginpage with a button and I'd added this code to that button's method.

Comment: Your Loginpage has navigation controller ?

Comment: yes my loginpage is directed from a splashscreenviewcontroller, which inturn has a navigation controller, which is the entry point of the storyboard.

Comment: Just remove the navigation controller from the Home page which you have added in image and try.

Comment: that's fixed, thanks shouldn't we use more than one navigation controllers in a single storyboard?

Comment: Yes we don't required two navigation controller as we have already taken in rootviewcontroller. If you change your rootviewcontroller at runtime and it not contains navigation controller then you can add. Also when you present any controller modally and it not contain navigation controller then you can add other navigation controller.

Comment: we can use navigation controller but it based on requirenment. When you are using tab controller then we have to embed each tab controller to navigation controller.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for the information. I tried to up vote, but I don't have the required reputation to do that yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the following line

```
[self.navigationController showViewController: dbvc sender:self];
```

To

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: dbvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** According to image, You are connect view-Controller to Segue, Then Why you are push controller use of Code. Doesn't required code, Because you connect view-controller with segue.

May Be, You are segue selected Kind Type is Present Model, Click on segue and change is show (Push). See image :

[image]